# Prove $ \sum \frac{cos(n)} { \sqrt n}$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis

Prove $ \sum \frac{\cos(n)} { \sqrt n}$ is bounded.

How can I prove $\sum \cos(n)$ is bounded. Can It be done using $\cos$ as real part of complex number as I showed in question ?

Comment: Yes your approach is right. I believe you want to prove the convergence of the series using Dirichlet test.

Comment: Are you trying to show $\sum \frac {\cos n}{\sqrt n}$ converges?

Comment: yes i am but using abels theorem

Comment: Fine, but you stated a different problem. I will edit now.